# What's the easiest way to extract contour of segmented image?

Tags: image, octave, contour

Let's say i have an image like that one:

[image: Original image]

After some quick messing around, i got a binary image of the axe, like that:
[image: Extracted image]

What is the easiest/fastest way to get the contour of that image using GNU/Octave?

Comment: Just an idea, not sure really sure the best way. Loop through the image, and use vector to store points that stick out. The axe starting at top left would be the start. Loop through with GetPixel() going horizontally. Depending on how accurate you want, can add the top lower point otherwise the next point would be the top right of the axe. Once back at the start point, you have a vector of all the main points. Edit: I think you are doing something else, nevermind.

Comment: Haha, i guess i'm trying to do something else indeed, but thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Octave you can use `bwboundaries` (but I will welcome patches that implement `bwtraceboundaries`)

```
octave:1> pkg load image;
octave:2> bw = logical (imread ("https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoQPe.jpg"));
octave:3> boundaries = bwboundaries (bw);
octave:4> boundaries = cell2mat (boundaries);
octave:5> imshow (bw);
octave:6> hold on
octave:7> plot (boundaries(:,2), boundaries(:,1), '.g');
```

There are a couple of differences here from @Benoit_11 answer:

1. here we get the boundaries for all the objects in the image. `bwboundaries` will also accept coordinates as input argument to pick only a single object but I believe that work should be done by further processing your mask (may be due to the jpeg artifacts)
2. because we get boundaries for all objects, so you get a cell array with the coordinates.  This is why we are using dots to plot the boundaries (the default is lines and it will be all over the image as it jumps from one object to other). Also, it is not documented whether the coordinates given are for the continuous boundary, so you should not assume it (again, why we plot dots).
3. the image that is read seems to have some artifacts, I will guess that is from saving in jpeg.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [bwtraceboundary](http://wiki.octave.org/Image_package) in the Image package. Here is the Matlab implementation but that should be pretty similar using Octave:

First estimate starting pixel to look for boundary and then plot (BW is the image). (Check [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/boundary-tracing-in-images.html) )

```
dim = size(BW);
col = round(dim(2)/2)-90;
row = min(find(BW(:,col)));

boundary = bwtraceboundary(BW,[row, col],'N');

imshow(BW)
hold on;
plot(boundary(:,2),boundary(:,1),'g','LineWidth',3);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did found that, but it seems the bwtraceboundary function isn't implemented on Octave's image package yet.

Comment: oh shoot then sorry about that!

Comment: @ebernardes in Octave there is http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/function/bwboundaries.html

Comment: Use the @ symbol to be sure @carandraug gets notified of your comment :)  I thought this function was not available in Octave haha but that should work!